# WQ, WK, WV matrix used for generating query, key and value vector for Attention in Transformers are fixed or WQ, WK and WV are dependent on input word

Tags: huggingface-transformers, attention-model, self-attention, multihead-attention

To calculate self-attention,
For each word, we create a Query vector, a Key vector, and a Value vector.
These vectors are created by multiplying the embedding by three matrices that we trained during the training process defined as WQ, WK, WV matrix.

Question: are these matrices WQ, WK, WV same for every input word (embedding) or they are different for different different words?

[Paper link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.03762.pdf)

Comment: See http://nlp.seas.harvard.edu/annotated-transformer/